# Java: Find if String is "_\\d$" and replace that last number in square bracket

Tags: java

I have a Strings in Java, which ends in _[number], example abc_234 and I want it as abc[234].

What is the easy way to convert those?

Thanks

Comment: `"abc_234".replaceAll("_(\\d+)$", "[$1]")`

Comment: if you know that it will always have this format use: `str=str.replace("_","[")+"]";`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, And what about strings like "_abc_123"?

Comment: `"if you know that it will always have this format"`@ИгорьДобровольський

Comment: I don't need for _abc_123, only the last _ need to be replaced with square bracket.

Comment: String testString = "aaaa_134234";int index = testString.lastIndexOf("_");
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(testString).replace(index, index+1,"[").append("]").toString());

Comment: I tried this 
if(s.matches("_\\d$")) s = s.replaceAll("_(\\d+)$", "[$1]"); But it is not even going into my if clause. What is the issue there?

Comment: `s = s.replaceFirst("_(\\d+)$", "[$1]");` of @saka1029 without `if`. replaceFirst will return the original string if not found. Or `if (s.matches(".*_\\d+")) ...`

Comment: Thanks @saka1029 and Joop Eggen It worked.